# Get the service object from access token (google-api-python-client)

Tags: python, oauth, google-plus, google-api-python-client

The documentation google + domains api to create a post using the 'service' object, obtained here [by this method](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20). But in my project to authenticate via google and other sites I use the python social auth 
and after authorization I have a ready access token.
The problem lies in the fact that I need a service object to work with api, but I can not figure out how to get it already having access token. Please help me and sorry for my english.

Comment: [an example of the creation of the post](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating#creating_a_post)

Answer (score 0):

For the domains API, you typically will implement using a [service account authorization flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) - which is not retrieved in the same way as a user OAuth flow. This is because service accounts can be authorized for services that users typically should not be authorized for (e.g. retrieving domain-wide lists of user names).

The service account credentials, used to authorize your application, are created using the [Google Developer Console](https://console.developer.google.com) and then are downloaded as a JSON or p12 file that is used to [authenticate your Python client, as shown in this example](https://github.com/playgameservices/management-tools/blob/master/publishing-sample/jwt_auth.py).

That said, you still can do some actions with that access token which is why the auth flow you're seeing is doing this. Service credentials are how you should be authorizing for domains-related management features which may explain the behavior you're seeing.